# Average monthly weather data by city, over the world?

Tags: data-request, api, weather

I'm searching for any website or dataset that provides average monthly weather, such as highest and lowest temperature, humidity, and number of rainy days, by city over the world (major city).

For example, the dataset that consists of the following:

- Highest average temperature

  - City | January | February | March | ...
  - Seoul | 8.3 | 9.3 | 11.5 | ...
  - Hong Kong | 15.5 | 18.3 | 23.6 | ...
- Lowest average temperature

  - City | January | February | March | ...

Is there any website or dataset that provides them? I don't like a website that you must dig up all the cities one by one, like [the following](http://www.holiday-weather.com/bangkok/averages/july/) (which you can find many, many on the Web). I mean, I want to get all the cities directly in comparison.